# Nodejs Include file to generate a front-end API

Tags: jquery, node.js

Assuming I will work in front-end library(like jQuery for exemple),
I'll need develop multiples modules(query/touch/ajax...). 
all these modules need to belong to the library by $,inside anonymous function, like:

```
(function(){
  ajax = function(){};
  window.$ = function(){...}
})()
```

But ajax needs be in another separated file.

The question is: how include another file inside this main file, white nodejs, compile it, and generate the final file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Browserify for this.  It allows you to use `require()`, and even most of the Node.js libraries if you want.  It generates one big bundle within a closure, and is very configurable.

You can run it standalone, or embed it into your Node.js application.

http://browserify.org/

Comment: But with Browserify generate a dependency right ?
I want include all modules inside a main module and "compile" it in a final independent library.
its possible Browserify Browserify ?

Comment: @MateusVahl That's exactly what Browserify does.  It compiles all of your modules into a single library.

Comment: this is exactly I search for. I'd better search but I'm so embarrassed with unnecessary school things, thnks